# Why do I need the parent of the reference element when using `insertBefore()`?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I want to insert `newEl` before `refEl` I must use

```
refEl.parentNode.insertBefore(newEl, refEl);
```

Why did w3c decide that?

For me, the two options below make more sense

- `insertBefore` expecting only one argument:

  ```
  refEl.insertBefore(newEl);  /* or */  newEl.insertBefore(refEl);
  ```
- Only `document` has `insertBefore`

  ```
  document.insertBefore(newEl, refEl);
  ```

Why did w3c want us to specify the redundant parent element?

Maybe is there any advantage I don't see?

Comment: Why did they decide this? I think you'd have to ask the designers. The DOM Level 4 does define `.before()` and `.after()`, which allow for insertion directly relative to the target.

Comment: do yourself a favor: don't ever ask "Why did they do X?" about anything DOM-related.

Comment: This is just a piece of speculation: It's known that DOM was a compromise between manufacturers who already had document-manupulation APIs, and that as a result there are a number of peculiar features of DOM. It's also known that IE, before IE10, could when given certain forms of invalid HTML markup, build an internal object model that wasn't a perfect tree structure and therefore couldn't be mapped exactly onto the DOM API. In such situations, refEl can be the child of more than one element and getting refEl.parent throws a error. Specifying the parent explicitly would avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a linked list, it needs the parent to change that 'next' link.  With just the single node, it doesn't have enough information to complete the operation.

Comment: Yes, because with `refNode.parentElement` you get the parent element, so it's redundant. But could you clarify a bit, or provide an example? I'm not sure if I understand well your answer.

Comment: It seems they didn't want the insert command to finding the parentNode internally.  They may be some problem situations/cases for doing that (like, what if it didn't have a parent?)

Comment: But even if it doesn't have any parent I don't find it too difficult to handle. The method could return `false` or `null` instead of `newEl`, or it could throw an error.

Comment: There are many exceptions that are thrown due to invalid insertion operations. If there's no parent, then that would just be another exception.

Comment: .insertBefore seems to mean "insert before this node I am pointing to".  If that's true, then I can see why they want the parentNode as well.